# Looking for a nodejs stream module that converts its chunks into a string

Tags: node.js, stream

I have been using node streams in the last few weeks and I have been finding it easier to use some of the ready stream modules (from github/substack, github/mikeal and github/Raynos) than actually use the stream methods directly.

There is one thing the evades me:

What is the simplest way to extract the data out of a readable stream, when you know that there is no more data coming?

I think the easiest way would be to pipe that readable stream into a writable stream that
would expose a method (or property) that returns all the data that has been written onto it.

Here is an example of how I would use it to extract all the data captured in a spawned stderr:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    proc = spawn('some_command'),
    plug = require('the-stream-module-i-am-looking-for');

buffer = plug.buffer();
proc.stderr.pipe(buffer);
proc.on('exit', function() { console.log(buffer.getdata()); }
```

I have looked at the [Raynos/buffer-stream](https://github.com/Raynos/buffer-stream),  BufferedStream from [mikeal/morestreams](https://github.com/mikeal/morestreams) but their goal seems to be different.

I understand that capturing all the data like that is not ideal - occasionally though its necessary.
I also understand that I can achieve what I want be writing the simple code, that either

1. implements the _read function to capture/concatenate the incoming
   chunks into a string
2. (classic style) listens on 'data' events to
   do the same
3. goes in the stream after the fact and joins the
   chunks into a string

but all of the above seem like a code that must have been written by now thousands of times by  thousands of people. Hopefully, one of them abstracted these couple lines of code into a single module function. Or there is something simpler that I may have missed - as I mentioned I still don't feel confident that I understand nodejs streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Max Ogden's [node-concat-stream](https://github.com/maxogden/node-concat-stream) does what you describe.

Comment: You are right! So the code above will become
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    proc = spawn('some_command'),
    concat = require('concat-stream');

var console_flusher = concat(function(data) {console.log(data); })
proc.stderr.pipe(console_flusher);
`